# How to change whole link in url bar when page opens not just URL?

Tags: javascript, html

I figured out how to change url but can i change whole link. For example if user opens stackoverflow.com it will show him exmaple.com. This is the code i've used so far for chaning the URL only:

```
window.history.pushState(“object or string”, “Title”, “/new-url”);
```

Comment: trying to b fishing hmm :)

Answer (score 2):

This is impossible.

`pushState` allows you to update the local part of a URL so that you can provide a direct URL to a page that you have constructed piecemeal with JavaScript.

It doesn't let you pretend to be a different website, which would be a serious security risk (as it would make an effective phishing technique). That is why [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#dom-history-pushstate) expressly forbids it:

> Compare the resulting parsed URL to the result of applying the URL parser algorithm to the document's address. If any component of these two URLs differ other than the path, query, and fragment components, then throw a SecurityError exception and abort these steps.